# PlUpload : select folders feature

Tags: javascript, plupload

Thanks to PlUpload library, I would like to upload folder through window dialog.

It's possible and explained [here](http://www.plupload.com/docs/Required-Features). (search for "select_folder").

Nevertheless, there is no explanations in PlUpload [website](http://www.plupload.com/docs/Options).

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <ul id="filelist"></ul>
    <br />

    <div id="container">
        <a id="browse" href="javascript:;">[Browse...]</a>
        <a id="start-upload" href="javascript:;">[Start Upload]</a>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/plupload.full.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
          browse_button: 'browse', // this can be an id of a DOM element or the DOM element itself
          url: 'upload.php',
          select_folder:1, 
          drag_and_drop:0
        });

        uploader.init();
    </script>
</body>
```

This code does not work. So, what is the problem with it?

Thanks in advance :)

Have a good day.

Comment: so what are you missing?

Comment: @mikus Tell me what I'm missing, because the website tells that is working on Chrome > v11 and I'm using the lastest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to use a Moxie object.

```html
        <body>
            <ul id="filelist"></ul>
            <br />

            <div id="container">
                <a id="browse" href="javascript:;">[Browse...]</a>
                <a id="start-upload" href="javascript:;">[Start Upload]</a>
            </div>


            <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/plupload.full.min.js" ></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
                  url: 'upload.php'
                });
                uploader.init();

                var input = new mOxie.FileInput({
                  browse_button: 'browse',
                    multiple: false,
                    directory: true
                });

                input.init();
            </script>
        </body>
```